# Chrome use ajax cached version when back is pressed

Tags: ajax

I use ajax request beside pushing history state to load new content and update the entire page. At the server the X-Requested-With header is used to decide to send the full page or just the content. But it seems chrome tends to use the cache no matter it's loaded with ajax or normal request (it doesn't respect headers when checking the cache).

The problem happens when I open a site page, I click a link to navigate to a new page using ajax then navigate to a new page by entering the url in address bar. When I hit back the ajax cached version (no matter it's html or json) is shown instead of full page. When the cache is disabled everything works fine.

Is there any way to force chrome respect the request headers when checking the cache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research I found out that browsers tend to cache responses base on Request Method as well as URL. So they won't consider any request headers when checking the cache by default. But it's possible to force the browser to respect some headers when checking the cache by using Vary header.

So by adding this header (**Vary:X-Requested-With**) to each response that changes based on X-Requested-With request header, server is telling browser that this response may vary if your X-Requested-With header is changed and you must request a new response.